# GNU Make wildcard-expanded explicit lists of targets and prerequisites order

Tags: makefile

There is a simple task.

There are two directories - **in** and **out**.

Initial state

```
$ tree .
.
├── in
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   └── 3
├── Makefile
└── out
    ├── 1
    ├── 2
    └── 3
```

where 1, 2, 3 are empty files.

Now,

```
$ touch in/*
```

Goal is to print file name in directory **in** that is newer than corresponded file in directory **out**, for ex.: **in/2** -> **out/2**.

Makefile is

```
out/* : in/*
    @ echo $?
```

run it

```
$ make -rd

...
 Prerequisite 'in/3' is newer than target 'out/3'.
 Prerequisite 'in/2' is newer than target 'out/3'.
 Prerequisite 'in/1' is newer than target 'out/3'.
...
```

Order is not preserved.

Can someone help to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your makefile doesn't do what you're hoping.  It will expand to:

```
out/1 out/2 out/3 : in/1 in/2 in/3
        @ echo $?
```

This is NOT the same thing as saying that each `in` file is a prerequisite of its specific `out` file.  The above is identical to writing:

```
out/1 : in/1 in/2 in/3
        @ echo $?
out/2 : in/1 in/2 in/3
        @ echo $?
out/3 : in/1 in/2 in/3
        @ echo $?
```

which is to say, each `out` file depends on *ALL* the `in` files.  That's why you get the output you do.

Also note `make` only builds the first target it finds in the makefile (and all prerequisites of that target of course), which is why you don't see any info for the other `out` files.  You need a first target such as `all` that depends on all the `out` files.

You need to either use three explicit rules:

```
.PHONY: all
all: out/1 out/2 out/3

out/1 : in/1
        @ echo $?
out/2 : in/2
        @ echo $?
out/3 : in/3
        @ echo $?
```

(which requires knowing up-front which files), or else using a pattern rule:

```
.PHONY: all
all: out/*

out/% : in/%
        @ echo $?
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. There is another question that expand  this problem to the next level, I will create it at S.O. soon, hope you help again)