# GNU Make | How to create dependency between source code hierarchy and compiler output h-hy?

Tags: makefile, gnu

Some code from `Makefile`:

```
tempDir := ...
javaSources := $(wildcard src/java/**/%.java)
javaClasses := $(subst src/java, $(tempDir)/java/classes, $(subst .java,.class, $(javaSources)))

$(javaClasses): $(javaSources)
  mkdir -p $(tempDir)/java/classes || true
  javac \
    -d  $(tempDir)/java/classes \
    -cp $(tempDir)/java/classes \
  $?
```

How to create a pattern rule (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55720563/gnu-make-wildcard-expanded-explicit-lists-of-targets-and-prerequisites-order)) to preserve in / out order?

@MadScientist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `wildcard` won't work.  GNU make uses only basic shell globbing, which means it can't understand advanced globbing like `**` meaning "search all subdirectories".  Second, `%` is not a shell globbing character at all so you're just looking for files that are literally named `%.java`.

Instead you probably want something like this:

```
javaSources := $(shell find src/java -name '*.java')
```

Next, to create the `javaClasses` content you really don't want to use `subst` because it substitutes everywhere which can give false matches (e.g., `$(subst .x,.y,foo.xbar)` will yield `foo.ybar` which is probably not what you want).

Something like this is simpler to understand:

```
javaClasses := $(patsubst src/java/%.java,$(tempdir)/java/classes/%.class,$(javaSources))
```

Finally, you are repeating exactly the same error you made in the previous question, where you tried to list all the targets and all the prerequisites in the same rule.  Just as I said for that question, that is not right.

The answer is exactly the same as in the previous question: you should write a pattern rule that describes how to build *one single target* from *one single source file*.

And again you need an `all` target or similar which depends on all the outputs.

Comment: Big thanks for reply! Main problem here for me - how to write correct pattern rule in this case.

Comment: In the previous example stuff was in 2 one-level hierarchy, in this case it's more complex.

Comment: Patterns in GNU make don't care about directories.  They do string-matching without regard to directory separators (for the most part).  So as long as you want to keep the same hierarchy in the source and class areas you have no problem.

Comment: In any event, adding more complexity doesn't mean you should continue to try to use the exact same method which was shown to be incorrect previously :).  Instead you should try to adapt the correct method from the previous question into your new environment, and show _that_ here in your question (only _after_ you've tried and can't get it to work).  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In complement to [MadScientist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939557/madscientist) answer, you should probably use a pattern rule like:

```
$(tempDir)/java/classes/%.class: src/java/%.java
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    javac -d $(dir $@) -cp $(dir $@) $<
```

(not sure what `-cp` should be in this case, it depends on your specific project). And as [MadScientist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939557/madscientist) also suggested, you will need:

```
.PHONY: all
all: $(javaClasses)
```

such that you can call `make all` to compile all the source files that need to be. Put it before any other explicit target if you want `all` to be the default goal (the goal make selects if you just call `make`), or use the `.DEFAULT_GOAL` special variable:

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all
```

Comment: `javac` recreates packages structure of a source code at a directory level. We get explicit lists of dependencies and explicit list of classes that are not exist yet but but must copy directory structure of sources. How we can tell `make` to create at runtime  implicit rule "changed source files" - "desired classes"? @Renaud Pacalet @MadScientist